# Detect that from which Page I come to the current Page

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, viewcontroller

I want to know how to do this:

I have 3 view controllers and the first and second view controller are connected to the third one !
I want to know how can I write a code that detect from which one I came to this view controller

I have searched here for my answer But all of the similar questions asked about navigation !!!
The Important thing is that I don't have navigation in my app!!

Comment: you can maintain boolean variable say `isFromFirst` to detect and pass true false while navigating

Comment: I don't have navigation in my app I edited the question

Comment: If you don't have navigation then how are you navigating? Will you please elaborate and show us some code snippet in order to help you properly ?

Comment: I have TabBar and some codes that take me to another pages I want to use this if for example I came from page 1 to page 3 show some thing and if I came from page 2 to page 3 show me some thing else

Comment: I want to write some thing that print last page

Comment: you may use notificationcenter

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that like simply passing a view controller as a property to the new instance. But in your case it might make more sense to create a static variable which holds the stack of the view controllers the same way the navigation controller does that.

If you are doing this only between the `UIViewController` subclasses I suggest you to create another subclass of it form which all other view controllers inherit. Let us call it `TrackedViewController`.

```
class TrackedViewController : UIViewController {

    static var currentViewController: TrackedViewController?
    static var previousViewController: TrackedViewController?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        TrackedViewController.previousViewController = TrackedViewController.currentViewController
        TrackedViewController.currentViewController = self
    }
}
```

Now you need to change all the view controllers you want to track so that they all inherit from `TrackedViewController` as `class MyViewController : TrackedViewController {`. And that is pretty much it. Now at any point anywhere in your project you can find your current view controller via `TrackedViewController.currentViewController` and the previous view controller via `TrackedViewController.previousViewController`. So you can say something like:

```
if let myController = TrackedViewController.previousViewController as? MyViewController {
    // Code here if the screen was reached from MyViewController instance
}
```

Now the way I did it was through the instance of the view controller which may have some side effects.

1. The biggest problem you may have is that the previous controller is being retained along with the current view controller. That means you may have 2 controllers in memory you do not need.
2. If you go from controller `A` to `B` to `C` and back to `B` then the previous view controller is `C`, not `A`. This might be desired result or not.
3. The system will ignore all other view controllers. So if you use one that is not a subclass of `TrackedViewController` the call will be ignored: `A` to `B` to `UITableViewController` to `C` will report that the `C` was presented by `B` even though there was another screen in between. Again this might be expected result.

So if the point 2 and 3 are good to you then you should only decide weather to fix the point 1. You may use `weak` to remove the retaining on the two properties but then you lose the information of the previous view controller if the controller is deallocated. So another choice is to use some identifiers:

```
class TrackedViewController : UIViewController {

    static var currentViewControllerID: String?
    static var previousViewControllerID: String?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        TrackedViewController.previousViewControllerID = TrackedViewController.currentViewControllerID
        TrackedViewController.currentViewControllerID = self.screenIdentifier
    }

    var screenIdentifier: String {
        return "Default Screen" // TODO: every view controller must override this method and have unique identifier
    }

}
```

Also you may replace strings with some enumeration or something. Combining them with some associated values could then create quite a powerful tool.

Comment: I tested it and it works. The code does not compile though as wrote at by hard. Let me fix it...

Comment: I just want to use this function ( if previous page is for example myView Controller { print("OK") }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer will help you in your specific case, but here is the implementation I see from what you are asking. Maybe it will inspire you.

So imagine your are in your homePage or whatever viewController and you want to navigate throw other, but you want to know from which viewController you came from.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:segue_VC1]) {
        CustomViewController1* destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationVC.fromSegue = @"I AM VC 1";
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:segue_VC2]) {
        CustomViewController2* destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationVC.fromSegue = @"I AM VC 2";
    }
}
```

The more important thing you have to know is that you can access attribute from the destination view controller you will access with your segue.

I know this is in Obj C, but the implementation is still the same.

So that when you navigate from a ViewController to an other one, you can set the attribute of the destinationViewController.

Then when you are in the view controller you wanted to navigate you can check :

```
if ([_fromSegue isEqualToString: "I AM VC 1"])
  // do specific stuff when you come from VC 1
else if ([_fromSegue isEqualToString: "I AM VC 2"])
  // do specific stuff when you come from VC 2
else
  // other case
```